# groupby cumsum sorted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I want to group a dataframe by a column then apply a cumsum over the other ordered by the first column descending

```
df1:
id   PRICE  DEMAND
0      120     10
1      232     2
2      120     3
3      232     8
4      323     5
5      323     6
6      323     2

df2:
id   PRICE  DEMAND
0      323     13
1      232     23
2      120     36
```

I do it in two instructions but I am feeling it can be done with only one sum

```
data = data.groupby('PRICE',as_index=False).agg({'DEMAND': 'sum'}).sort_values(by='PRICE', ascending=False)
data['DEMAND'] = data['DEMAND'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have seems perfectly fine to me. But if you want to chain everything together, first `sort` then `groupby` with `sort=False` so it doesn't change the order. Then you can `sum` within group and `cumsum` the resulting Series

```
(df.sort_values('PRICE', ascending=False)
   .groupby('PRICE', sort=False)['DEMAND'].sum()
   .cumsum()
   .reset_index())

   PRICE  DEMAND
0    323      13
1    232      23
2    120      36
```

---

Another option would be to `sort` then `cumsum` and then `drop_duplicates`:

```
(df.sort_values('PRICE', ascending=False)
   .set_index('PRICE')
   .DEMAND.cumsum()
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates('PRICE', keep='last'))

   PRICE  DEMAND
2    323      13
4    232      23
6    120      36
```

Comment: Or you can `groupby().sum()` then `sort_values/sort_index` to save some sorting operations. Not that it's significant anyway.